# what is the purpose of cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I tried searching over internet about the purpose,use and implementation of cursor in SQL.I found some answers they were very explained in very bookish type of language and the examples were way complicated to understand the function itself.I am new to database/SQL so can somebody please explain cursor with a simple example.

Comment: I'll probably catch some flack for this,but who'ever the rocket scientist is that downvoted this give @Auguster a break. We've all had those questions that just needed a little more of a nudge to get it.  Particularly as he's a new member, we want to encourage all levels of questions.  It enriches the community.

Comment: @MattAkers Thanks for the answer and encouraging comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At its simplest form a cursor is used to iterate over rows of a result set.  Imagine a row as an object inside a list. With a cursor you have access to just that row.

If you're familiar with a foreach loop in other coding languages you are accomplishing a lot of the same function.

This link wasn't too bookish. [Non Bookish Description](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/27387/cursor-databases)

Answer (score 6):

A cursor allows you to perform operations on your data on a row-by-row basis. For example, calling a stored procedure for each row in a table in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @id_variable int

DECLARE the_cursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT id FROM SomeTable 

OPEN the_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @id_variable

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC MyStoredProcedure @id_variable

    FETCH NEXT FROM the_cursor INTO @id_variable
END

CLOSE the_cursor
DEALLOCATE the_cursor
```

In general, cursors should be avoided, if possible, as they are cumbersome to work with and perform poorly.